# Structuring a RESTful service to respond when no results found

Tags: rest

I'm building a RESTful service with Symfony2.

It has a search function which returns a search entity, the entity has an array of results.

If the user performs an improper search there are a few different messages I may need to send them. Thus, My thought on how to structure the response is:

For a good search:

```
{
  "message": "OK",
  "search": <insert search object here>
}
```

and for a bad search:

```
{
  "message: "Please double check your search in such and such fashion"
}
```

Essentially, always sending a "message" but not always sending a search entity, as one will not have been created if their search failed in certain ways.

Then, I will always return a 200 response, even when their search criteria were off. Or, if there were no results.

Does this jive with the thinking behind REST, or should I be changing the response to a 404 or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on how you want to structure your RESTful service.  When you say *If the user performs an improper search* to me that sounds like the user is using bad syntax in the search or doing something else wrong, as opposed to a properly formatted search that simply returns no results.

If that's the case I think most REST services return 400 - bad request, or some other error code in the 400 range.

Also, I think most REST services would return the search entity in the response body.

Comment: In my case, this is actually an image search. The user can upload an image, and it may not meet our criteria as searchable. It's not like they forgot to upload an image, they just included one that, for a variety of reasons, we weren't able to operate upon. So, it's kind of a fuzzy line. Not sure if this changes your response-

Comment: Just to follow up, after a bit more research I went with your suggestion. I'm returning a 400 status code when they either don't upload an image, or upload an unacceptable image. Rather than constantly returning a "message" in the response body I've added this message to a the response header as X-Status-Reason.